# The type of one of the expressions in the join clause is incorrect. Type inference failed in the call to 'Join'

Tags: c#, linq

I am using the below query to join two tables.

```
IQueryable<BoaPieceConsole> pieceConsoleQueryable;
                pieceConsoleQueryable = (from js in rewriteEntity.JobSummaries
                                         where js.ProductCode != null
                                         join bffd in rewriteEntity.BOAFinalFileDatas
                                         on new { js.JobID, prodCode = js.ProductCode } equals new { bffd.ADFJobID, prodCode = bffd.ProductCode }
                                         where js.ProductCode.Equals(ConsoleConstants.DAMAGED_PROD_CODE, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
                                         && js.ProcessDate >= startDate
                                         select new DamageConsoleModel
                                         {
                                             JobID = js.JobID,
                                             Productcode = js.ProductCode
                                         });
```

I have figured out the problem but was unable to figure out the solution for this problem.
JobSummaries table column ProductCode is of nullable type but BOAFinalFileDatas ProductCode is non-nullable. Due to which the join is throwing a compile time error stating:

*The type of one of the expressions in the join clause is incorrect.  Type inference failed in the call to 'Join'.*

**The datatype of ProductCode column is of varchar.**

How should I fix this?

Comment: Use `js.ProductCode.Value` and also alias `bffd.ADFJobID` to `JobId`.

Comment: @GertArnold - I am getting ```string does not contain a definition for Value```.

Comment: @GertArnold - My bad, totally missed to mention the data type. Updated the question body as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you need to change the name of at least part of one of your composite keys so that they match.

See here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/linq/join-by-using-composite-keys

Something like:

```
on new { JobID = js.JobID, prodCode = js.ProductCode } equals new { JobID = bffd.ADFJobID, prodCode = bffd.ProductCode }
```